# how to fetch audio files in their original format PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

```
<?php 
$user  = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE user_id='$user'" ;
$result = $conn->query($sql) ;
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows ;
chdir("uploaded/");
$dir = getcwd();
if($row_cnt > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        chdir($dir.'/'.$row['al_id'].'/');
        $curr_dir =  getcwd();
    }
}

$files1 = scandir($curr_dir);
print_r($files1);

?>
```

Everytime a user uploads a album a new folder is created inside the 'uploaded' directory now i don't know how to fetch them in audio format instead of string

Comment: in which format you save/upload in folder?

Comment: i am using only audio/mpeg

Comment: if you save the file name in database then get name from database and use file path to load audio in your browser.

Comment: @downtown You have to play the mp3 at clientside???

Comment: @MubasharIqbal  that will work but how can i do it for more than one album from the same user i mean fetch audio files from multiple folders

Comment: @MohitKumar yes

Comment: create folder by database record id and then it would be simple for you to build path. like files/audio/user_id/record_id/audiofile

Comment: @MubasharIqbal  yes i have been doing that

Comment: @downtown You can store the filepath as a variable in PHP & embed it with <embed src="file.mp3">

Comment: @MubasharIqbal This is my folder https://imgur.com/a/cHePa and this is my database https://imgur.com/a/GwI3r

Comment: @MohitKumar but how to handle more than one file path

Comment: @downtown why u inserting its full path structure in table, not only file name.

Comment: no no, don't use absolute path and save path with forward slash. you have problem in path.

Comment: @MohitKumar this is my code https://imgur.com/a/uEtcl when i try to insert the only the folder name  it creates an error invalid path in 'move_uploaded_file'